# CS50 interview question - Find longest substring recursive mystery - why test case #4 does not work?

Tags: python, recursion, cs50

**The question:**

> Given a string, find the length of the longest substring without
> repeating characters. For instance, in the string "abcabcbb", the
> length of the longest substring without repeating characters is 3
> ("abc", among others).

**Description of the problem:**

Hi, I have used Python and recursive solution for this. Every test case works as expected except of TC4 and I have no idea why. It looks like when the final substring ("wekf") is found, it stays in the same iteration and starts with original(!) string again. How it can even have the original string still? The output is the totally unexpected "pwekf" ...
Please help me to solve this big mystery.

**Code:**

```
def find_longest_substring(string, longest=0):
    current_longest_string = ""
    
    for char, i in zip(string, range(len(string))):
        if char not in current_longest_string:
            current_longest_string = f'{current_longest_string}{char}'
        # if character is already in current_longest_string, count len() and 
        # start looking again from last spot
        else:
            longest = len(current_longest_string) \
                if len(current_longest_string) > longest else longest
            find_longest_substring(string[i:], longest)

    longest = len(current_longest_string)
    return longest, current_longest_string


# TC1
print(find_longest_substring("abcabcbb"))
# TC2
print(find_longest_substring("bbbbb"))
# TC3
print(find_longest_substring("abcdef"))
# TC4
print(find_longest_substring("pwwekf"))
# TC5
print(find_longest_substring(""))
```

FIXED:

```
def find_longest_substring(string, longest=0):
    current_longest_string = ""

    for char, i in zip(string, range(len(string))):
        if char not in current_longest_string:
            current_longest_string = f'{current_longest_string}{char}'
        # if character is already in current_longest_string, count len() and
        # start looking again from last spot
        else:
            longest = len(current_longest_string) \
                if len(current_longest_string) > longest else longest
            longest_new = find_longest_substring(string[i:], longest)
            if longest_new > longest:
                return longest_new

    longest = len(current_longest_string)
    return longest
```

**Output:**

```
(3, 'abc')
(1, 'b')
(6, 'abcdef')
(5, 'pwekf')
(0, '')
```

Comment: Could you please blur the screenshot a little more? It's too easy to read at the moment.

Comment: @Stef haha sorry, it was not the intention of course, I just make a screenshot from the video as I was too lazy to rewrite it. I think it is readable and additionally it is not so important anyway. It is easy to figure out what is the point.

Comment: *"For instance, in the string "absabcbb", the length of the longest substring without repeating characters is 3 ("abc", among others)."* What about 4 ("sabc")?

Comment: @Stef, man, that's exactly why I used the screen shot at first place .. it is just typo, should be "abcabcbb".

Answer (score 1):

You may notice this is the only testcase where the correct result doesn't start at the beginning. You may also notice your function is greedy, and can never back out of a wrong solution. The recursion does nothing, the output of the recursive call is used nowhere.

In the else path, you have to:

- make the recursive call
- check whether the solution is better than your current one
- if yes, replace it
- break out of the for loop

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer.  1. "make a recursive call" - don't I do it in else part? find_longest_substring(string[i:], longest), 2. "check whether solution is better than .." - don't I do it in longest = len(current_longest_string) \
                if len(current_longest_string) > longest else longest, 3. "if yes replace it" - same as 2 ...

Comment: @p-a No, you don't do anything with the results of your recursive call. You don't capture the result.

Comment: I understand now. I have fixed it, but honestly, little lost why it is working :)